# Protect string value in memory from catching

Tags: dart

How to secure string value in memory from capture by reverse engineering, such as a password or sensitive data.

Comment: you can just encrypt it and decrypted it when you need it

Comment: @Stanly What about the encryption key?? It needs to protection in memory too, so
this solution not useful

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68948859/

Answer (score 0):

If you use a string (or any other value) in Dart, there is no way to guarantee its erasure from memory.

Dart is a garbage-collected language, and decides on its own when to dispose of data. The language specification does not describe any way to ensure that sensitive data is cleared from memory.